# HotTowel SPA site launch with request paramters

Tags: durandal, hottowel

I have developed a website using the HotTowel SPA template. The need is for the users to access this SPA website from a hyperlink on another website with some parameters(query string/Post). I would need to access these paramters in the shell.js as the header.html view would need this data. The startmodule will be too late to access this information if I pass using :parm syntax in the hash tag.

Can you please advise the best way around.

Thanks in advance
Vik

Comment: Please share some code what you tried so far. There's not enough information in the question that would allow to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can access query string parameters in your shell.js through the window object.

```
window.location.search
```

[there is an article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#Example_.236.3A_Get_the_value_of_a_single_window.location.search_key.3A) showing this.